# My react app doesn't load on IOS ,Is there any specific react library that would prevent the page from loading on IOS devices?

Tags: ios, reactjs, framer-motion, react-scroll

I'm having trouble launching m website on IOS devices only.The link opens in Android phones and web browsers normally but when it comes to IOS devices it doesn't load anything and a white page appears.

This is the site https://regal-taffy-c1fc9d.netlify.app/

These are the `dependencies` that I've installed.

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "framer-motion": "^10.12.16",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.9",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  }
}
```

I already removed some dependencies that might affect the page from loading on IOS devices but still the same issue

Answer (score -1):

You can add down `react-scripts` version , something like this should work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).